# как поверх блока div закрепить картинку

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class='input_font_style'>Новый аватар<img src='../img/pin.svg' style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0;'></div>
```

как мне закрепить поверх блока изображение, но не поверх страницы! Потому что с моим кодом у меня изобажение поверх страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Родительскому блоку добавить `position: relative;` и относительно него располагать изображение как Вам необходимо (вверху\внизу\сбоку).